# How to save JPEGs for MAC OSX?

Tags: mac, adobe-photoshop, file-format

I am pretty sure that's a simple question, but I am not acquainted with MAC and its files formats at all, so:

**How to make a copy of exported JPEGs from Photoshop for MAC users or is there relevant settings in Photoshop?**

Again, sorry, but couldn't google it quickly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A jpg is a jpg. Macs don't need any special form.

The same can be said of almost any media type, except possibly wma or wmv, which are not supported though can be converted into supported formats.

Comment: Thanks. I thought files named with "._" were created for Mac users.

Comment: They're created by Macs on non-Mac volumes for files with resource-forks that Windows cannot use. Mac users, for instance, can tag files on remote Windows servers with a colour or category name, so the Mac user can see the file's tag colour & info, but no-one on Windows can. For such as a picture file, they can safely be ignored - Windows couldn't generate the necessary data anyway.